# how to get back my previous hostname?

Tags: boot, hostname

i wanted to change the name of my pc so i executed the command

```
sudo nano /etc/hostname and sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

to change the content of both of the files, but after rebooting, the pc displays a black screen and doesn't go further than this , is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: i'm using kubuntu 15.04

Comment: what contents has been changed? You want to get hostname or you want to fix the blackscreen? Please edit your question, be more organize and specific.

Comment: i mean i no longer can access to my session (account) and i guess it(s because of the hostname change !!

Comment: hostname change wont cause you a blackscreen.  However if you wrongly edit /etc/hosts then it will be different story. Can you access GRUB? Tell us what was change in those files?

Comment: i replaced the text which was the name of my pc by the name i wanted i saved the changes , then i rebooted my pc then oooops when the pc restarts a black screen is displayed , nothing to do
PS; the new name i chose was naszim@HP !! 
is the @ a prblm !!!! m a begginer on linux so don't blame me

Comment: yes, hostname cant contain `@`. No im not blaming on you. We all learning here. Next is to access GRUB and boot into emergency and clear the `@`.  Follow this [guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

Comment: well i coudln't do it with the GRUB ! but i coud fix it by mounting linux partition on windows then deleting the "@" 
thnks for ur help anyways